# AWS Amplify, set yml commands for a specific environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

My app has two environments: develop and production. Each environment has different npm commands to build a specific configuration.

my amplify.yml looks like this:

```
version: 1
frontend:
   phases:
       preBuild:
           commands: ['npm ci']
       build:
           commands: ['npm run build']
   artifacts:
       baseDirectory: dist/my-app
       files:
           - '**/*'
   cache:
       paths:
           - 'node_modules/**/*'
```

I need the `build` command to be different for production but I don't see a way to specify environment with the amplify.yml file

Answer (score 0):

Amplify provides a set of [default environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/environment-variables.html) you can use. You can use it like so (not super accurate though):

```sh
preBuild:
  commands:
    - if [ $AWS_BRANCH == 'prod' ] then npm run build:prod; else npm run build;
```

See this for conditional commands syntax: https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/build-settings.html) you have the documentation for conditional build

```
build:
  commands:
    - if [ $AWS_BRANCH == 'main' ] ; then npm run build:prod; fi
    - if [ $AWS_BRANCH == 'dev' ] ; then npm run build:dev; fi
```